# How can I add a delete button to every li element added in my list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already created a to do list that strikes a line through a list item when you click on it and I created one delete button that works. What I would like help with is how could I create a delete button for every li item that is added.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

ul.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === "LI") {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function deleteBtn() {
  var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    deleteButton.onclick = this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function createListElement() {
  var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}


function addListAfterKeypress() {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

btn1.addEventListener("click", deleteBtn);
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
ul li.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter list item here">
<button id="enter">Add</button>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>eggs</il><button id="btn1">delete</button>
    <li>milk</li>
    <li>tacos</li>
</ul>
```

In the deleteBtn function I tried adding

```
deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
deleteButton.appendChild.createTextNode("delete);
```

right after the for loop but I couldn't get it to work.
I also tried adding it in the createListElement function and I couldn't get that to work either. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just add the delete button in the `createListElement` method?

Comment: I tried that to and I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Let me try it. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a class - `.deletebtn` with each newly created `buttons` and attached an click eventlistner to each one which will execute separately.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

ul.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === "LI") {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}



function createListElement() {
  var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

  deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete"));
  li.appendChild(deleteButton);
  deleteButton.onclick = function() {
    this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}


function addListAfterKeypress() {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
ul li.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter list item here">
<button id="enter">Add</button>

<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one? It should work.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

ul.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === "LI") {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function deleteBtn() {
  var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    deleteButton.onclick = this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function createListElement() {
  var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerText = "delete";
  btn.onclick = () => ul.removeChild(li);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  li.appendChild(btn);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}


function addListAfterKeypress() {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

btn1.addEventListener("click", deleteBtn);
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
ul li.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter list item here">
<button id="enter">Add</button>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>eggs</il><button id="btn1">delete</button>
    <li>milk</li>
    <li>tacos</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please run the snippet before you post

Comment: @Rajesh I did, and it works fine. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Rajesh It does the same in the original code, if you like to try.

Comment: @Rajesh The question was "how could I create a delete button for every li item that is added." And I would say, that this is exactly what my code does. Enter something in the text field and add it to the list. A delete button will appear and if you click on it, it will delete the freshly added element.

Comment: @TrevorDavlin You are welcome! Woruld you please mark one answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

While adding the buttons and text you can combine both of them into `<li>` and hide the parent when delete is called.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

ul.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === "LI") {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function deleteBtn(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  obj.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}

function createListElement() {
  var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  let node = document.createElement('li');
  node.innerHTML = `${input.value}&nbsp;<button id="btn${myList.length}" onclick="deleteBtn(this)">delete</button>`;
  ul.appendChild(node);
  input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}


function addListAfterKeypress() {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

//btn1.addEventListener("click", deleteBtn);
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
ul li.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter list item here">
<button id="enter">Add</button>
<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```